# JSF: Absolutely need to put expensive Business Logic inside accessor method. How to avoid calling this expensive BL multiples time

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

Here is my dilemma, I know in JSF the accessor method will get call mutilple times, therefore I know not to put expensive business logic (like DB access) in accessor method. What if I absolutely have to put business logic into my accessor. What should I do in this case? Below are a high level layout of my dilemma. (Mojarra 2.1, GF 3.1)

```
<h:dataTable value="#{myBean.comments}" var="item1">
    <h:column>
          #{item1.name} says: #{item1.comment}
          <h:dataTable value="#{myBean.handleReplies(item1)}" var="item2">
               <h:column>
                   #{item2.name} replies: #{item2.comment}
               </h:column>
          </h:dataTable>    
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>    

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public void myBean(){
    private List<Comment> comments;

    @EJB
    private MyEJB myEJB;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        comments = myEJB.getAllComments();
    }

    //getters and setters for List<Comment> comments

    public List<Comment> handleReplies(Comment comment){
         //Return a List of replies of the comment
         return myEJB.getRepliesFromComment(comment); 
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `inner` dataTable take in the `item` of the `outer` dataTable to generate its List. Is there a way for somehow stop `handleReplies()` to be called multiple times, since this accessor method access DB.

Comment: Is it not an option to have a `#{item1.comments}` where lazy loading is just handled by JPA?

Comment: @BalusC: Can u explain a bit more, BalusC? I am not sure I understand what u mean

Comment: I'd naturally expect that `Comment` is a JPA entity which has a `@OneToMany List<Comment>` property which is lazily fetched by `FetchType.LAZY`. Or did you have reasons to not do so?

Comment: @BalusC: `Comment` is in fact JPA entity, which does has @OneToMany List<Comment>, but I dont have `FetchType.LAZY` to it. What does this `FetchType.LAZY` does, BalusC?

Comment: It will let JPA lazily load (and eventually cache) the children once the returned list is been iterated for the first time. They won't be loaded directly when you get only the parent(s). But since you already have .. Why don't you just use `#{item1.comments}` instead of `#{myBean.handleReplies(item1)}`?

Comment: @BalusC: I see what you are saying. Thank you. That is in fact a great idea as well. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. I've posted it as an answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a `HashMap` to create a view-scoped cache?

Something like:

```
private Map<Comment, List<Comment>> replies = new HashMap<Comment, List<Comment>>();

public List<Comment> handleReplies(Comment comment){
    if (!replies.containsKey(comment)) {
        replies.put(comment, myEJB.getRepliesFromComment(comment));
    }

    return replies.get(comment);
}
```

This way, your view-scoped bean store previous request results, and returns them if the request has already been done. If it hasn't, the request is made. In the end, no duplicate request!

Comment: This is actually a great idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can also just let JPA do the lazy loading and caching job (with a proper second level cache).

Assuming that your `Comment` entity look like this

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Comment.list", query="SELECT c FROM Comment c WHERE c.parent IS NULL")
public class Comment implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    private Comment parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", fetch=LAZY, cascade=ALL);
    private List<Comment> children;

    // ...
}
```

You could just use `#{comment.children}` to (lazily) get the children in a `<h:dataTable>`.